# Trying to understand the solution of the equation $\partial_x u=f$ with $f\in L^2$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I am studying the resolution of differential equations using the Fourier transform. In particular, I am trying to understand if the equation has a solution in some known space. I put a little context to understand what I say.

Let $L^2=L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (Add $n=1$)

For any $f\in L^2$, Is known that the equation $(I-\Delta)u=f$ has a unique solution $u$ in the space $H^{2}:=\left\{u\in L^2: (1+|\xi|^2)\widehat{u}(\xi)\text{ in } L^2\right\}$ (Sobolev space)

**My question 1** is: for any $f\in L^2$, the equation $\partial_x u=f$ has a unique solution in the space $H=\left\{u\in L^2: \xi\widehat{u}(\xi)\text{ in } L^2\right\}$?

I ask this because $\partial_x u=f$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\xi\widehat{u}(\xi))=f$ (where $\xi$ is the symbol of the operator $\partial_x$), then $u=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\frac{1}{\xi}\widehat{f}(\xi))$ and this $u$ is in $H$.   Is this interpretation correct? (I ask more than anything for the concern of the symbol $\frac{1}{\xi}$ when $\xi=0$)

**Question 2**. Is the space $H$ known or does it have a name in the literature? What books do you recommend to understand my questions? Thank you.

Comment: Is $\partial_xu$ the gradient of $u$ or a partial derivative of $u$?

Comment: $\zeta \in \mathbb R^n$ so you can’t just divide by $\zeta$. Also, I think that the Fourier transform of $\partial_ju(x)$ is $i \zeta_j \hat u (\zeta)$

Comment: $\partial_x$ u is the partial derivative of $u$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ sorry ($n=1$)